# spline update every second appear and disappear

Tags: highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I have an issue with spline chart update with every second. Chart redraw every time so it is not showing constant wave.

Here is image how it looks

[image]

I have tried like this

```
this.timeinterval = setInterval(() => {
    const x = (new Date()).getTime() + 7200000; // current time
    if (this.voltage) {
      this.chart['series'][0].addPoint([x, this.voltage], true, true);
    }
  }, 250);
```

How can i fix it to go smoothly.

Comment: Your code suggests the chart updates every 250 milliseconds, I don't think that is enough time for the chart to finish drawing before it gets a new point, which might be the issue. Try looking in the performance tab in console, to see what is going on in more detail.

Comment: I have changed to 1000 ms but the result is same. I am using same chart in ionic 3 mobile application there it is working fine.

Comment: Sorry i am checking conditional in my template that gets value every time that is why it takes some time to render graph. Thank you @ewolden